# C - Comparing each bit in two binary numbers

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

Say I have these binary numbers:

`0011100000000` **and**

```
0000111000000
```

How would I go about checking to see if these binary numbers have a 1 in the same bit?

Comment: AND that is an interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as punned by Martin, you want AND.

(0011100000000 & 0000111000000) will result in 0000100000000

Also read up on OR (|) and XOR (^)

Comment: to check for conflicts, could I write `if(a&b != 0){ printf("conflicting bits");}` ?